# Positioning of flexcaption - Flexslider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a slider using [Woothemes - Flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/). I have achieved only half of what I want. I placed the Direction-nav(next and previous arrows) and control-nav(dots) in requred place. What I actually want is I want the image and the caption to slide in down from the top. The problem is as the caption is fixed to the image. So, it is sliding down with the image. I want the caption at an absolute position like the bottom-right corner of the slide and it should change within a specified height like `100px`.

```js
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animationLoop: true,
  slideshowSpeed: "4000",
  slideshow: false,
  animation: "slide",
  animationSpeed: "500",
  direction: "vertical",
  reverse: true,
  smoothHeight: true,
  animationDuration: "2000",
  keyboard: "true",
  prevText: "Prev",
  nextText: "Next",
  start: function(slider) {
    $('body').removeClass('loading');
  },
  before: function() {
    $('.flex-caption').addClass("animated fadeInDown");
  },
  after: function(slider) {
    $('.flex-caption').removeClass("animated fadeInDown");
  },
});
```

```css
.flexslider {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flexslider .slides {
  height: 350px;
}

.slides li {
  height: 300px;
  //overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev,
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  position: absolute;
  right: 120px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next,
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 14px;
  right: -4%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.flex-control-nav {
  bottom: 180px;
  right: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  width: fit-content;
}

.flex-control-nav li {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
 .flex-caption {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: unset;
}

.caption-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 56px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.flexslider .slides img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px
}

.flex-control-paging li a {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(255, 21, 21, 0.9);
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 6px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="slider">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/kA0HcU/a.jpg" />
        <span class="caption-wrap">
        <p class="flex-caption">Adventurer Brownia</p>
          </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/kA0HcU/a.jpg" />
        <span class="caption-wrap">
        <p class="flex-caption">AdventurerCheesecakb</p>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/kA0HcU/a.jpg" />
        <span class="caption-wrap">
        <p class="flex-caption">Cheesecake Brownic</p>
          </span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</section>
```

This is the [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/pOMgmB).

This is my [Inspiration](https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/mGYOBg) (some custom slider) he has his captions one by one so this doesn't have any problem with the caption sliding animations.

Any amendments, suggestions and answer will be appreciated

Comment: What you want like your Inspiration design?

Comment: yes im only stuck at the flex caption thing

Comment: Your inspiration example is not a flexslider.

Comment: Yes, I know. I want the same effect in flexslider. If that were a flexslider I would have achieved what I want, but I need you people, to help.

Comment: Since the sliding happens by the whole `ul` element being moved by the translation, you would have to counter-act this movement by translating the captions by the same amount in the other direction simultaneously. And FYI, `p` nested into `span` is invalid HTML. If this extra wrapper is actually needed, then make it a `div` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I guess translating the captions will not make it dynamic. Is there something we can do through jQuery to make it dynamic. I got a pinch of knowledge on jQuery so could you help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexslider caption to be fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517085/flexslider-caption-to-be-fixed)