# Flexslider caption to be fixed

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

I'm working on flexslider everything is working fine but the problem is here when the slider is move caption also moving I don't want to be caption will not move with the slider. I want caption will be staying in the same place. Can anyone help me what might be the issue here I gave position absolute also but not working.

```js
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
  //animationLoop: true,
  slideshowSpeed: "4000",
  slideshow: false,
  animation: "slide",
  animationSpeed: "500",
  direction: "vertical",
  reverse: true,
  smoothHeight: true,
  animationDuration: "2000",
  keyboard: "true",
  prevText: "Prev",
  nextText: "Next",
  start: function(slider) {
    $(".flex-caption").addClass("animated fadeInDown");
  },
  before: function(slider) {
    $(".flex-caption").removeClass("animated fadeInDown");
  },
  after: function(slider) {
    $(".flex-caption").addClass("animated fadeInDown");
  }

});
```

```css
.flexslider {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flexslider .slides {
  height: 350px;
}

.slides li {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev,
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  position: absolute;
  right: 120px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next,
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 14px;
  right: -4%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.flex-control-nav {
  bottom: 180px;
  right: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  width: fit-content;
}

.flex-control-nav li {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.flex-caption {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: unset;
}

.caption-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 56px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
}

.flexslider .slides img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px
}

.flex-control-paging li a {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(255, 21, 21, 0.9);
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 6px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 0;
}

@keyframes fade-in-down {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    top: 25%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 50%;
  }
  75% {
    top: 70%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="slider">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/kA0HcU/a.jpg" />
        <span class="caption-wrap">
        <p class="flex-caption">Adventurer Brownia</p>
          </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/kA0HcU/a.jpg" />
        <span class="caption-wrap">
        <p class="flex-caption">AdventurerCheesecakb</p>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/kA0HcU/a.jpg" />
        <span class="caption-wrap">
        <p class="flex-caption">Cheesecake Brownic</p>
          </span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can remove `start`, `before` and `after` functions code

Comment: @ Sudharshan Nair i try but not getting

Comment: Can you run your snippet now, again

Comment: may be not possible but you can use swiper slider

Comment: possible exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52511265/positioning-of-flexcaption-flexslider

Answer (score 1):

Problem : You want to stop animation for `flex-caption`

> Solution :
>
> 1. Remove all `<span class="caption-wrap">` from `li`
> 2. Apply it before `<ul class="slides">`
> 3. Apply `z-index:999` to `.caption-wrap` class

Please check below code:

```js
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
    //animationLoop: true,
    slideshowSpeed: "4000",
    slideshow: false,
    animation: "slide",
    animationSpeed: "500",
    direction: "vertical",
    reverse: true,
    smoothHeight: true,
    animationDuration: "2000",
    keyboard: "true",
    prevText: "Prev",
    nextText: "Next",
    start: function (slider) {
        $(".flex-caption").addClass("animated");
    },
    before: function (slider) {
        $(".flex-caption").removeClass("animated");
    },
    after: function (slider) {
        $(".flex-caption").addClass("animated");
    }

});
```

```css
.flexslider .slides {
  height: 350px;
}

.slides li {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev,
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  position: absolute;
  right: 120px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next,
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 14px;
  right: -4%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.flex-control-nav {
  bottom: 180px;
  right: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  width: fit-content;
}

.flex-control-nav li {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.flex-caption {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: unset;
}

.caption-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 56px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
  z-index:999;
}

.flexslider .slides img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px
}

.flex-control-paging li a {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(255, 21, 21, 0.9);
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 6px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 0;
}

@keyframes fade-in-down {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    top: 25%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 50%;
  }
  75% {
    top: 70%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.1/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<section class="slider">
    <div class="flexslider">
        <span class="caption-wrap">
            <p class="flex-caption">Adventurer Brownia</p>
        </span>
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/kA0HcU/a.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/kA0HcU/a.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/kA0HcU/a.jpg" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Every slide has different content text.